# Is this site only for "how to act in a certain situation"?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some people seem to think that this site is only for question asking how to act in a particular situation. [Example comment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-can-i-do-to-moderate-my-talking-volume-better):

> I'm not sure how I feel about this question. I think it's a good one [...]. On the other hand, **the question isn't about how to act in a certain situation, which seems to be what most posts here are about**.

Is this site only for "how to act in a certain situation"?

Comment: I (the commenter) was talking about broadness there, because the question wasn't very specific as to the application of the skills - in other words, it felt a bit broad. That was my original intention. That said, I agree that we've seen a trend of questions like this, and the same thing's irked me lately. I don't *think* there should be such a limitation, as you put it below, but I do see that trend.

Comment: [Related meta question.](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/102)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limitation.

Social interaction does not always mean you are on the acting side. A legitimate question might be about a particular timeframe within which you are on the receiving side. Another legitimate question might just be trying to understand what is going on.

Actually, an "expert" of interpersonal skills is probably more someone who is capable of being a spectator of an interaction and understand all of the subtle things going on.

Other legitimate questions might be about the aftereffects of an interpersonal interaction.

We already have some great question that are not about how to act:

- [How can I notice if someone is speaking with sarcasm or irony?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-can-i-notice-if-someone-is-speaking-with-sarcasm-or-irony)
- [How do I avoid saying anything that comes to mind?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-do-i-avoid-saying-anything-that-comes-to-mind)
- [Will interacting on an electronic forum, tend to improve or deteriorate my real life interpersonal skills?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/32/will-interacting-on-an-electronic-forum-tend-to-improve-or-deteriorate-my-real)